# Receiving data with socket.io in a real time aplication

Tags: node.js, socket.io

When sending data via sockets, if the (on) function is inside other function, the data will be received just when the function is executed?

```
Server side 
socket.emit('sendArray',serverArray);

Client side
function updateClient(){
    socket.on('sendArray',serverArray)
    clientArray = serverArray;
}
setInterval(updateClient, 1000);
```

In this case the clientArray will just be set when the function updateClient is called and the socket.emit() was previosly callled?
If this is the case, would be a better efficient code to not wrap the socket.on() function inside other functions in the client

Comment: I think your socket.on method will be redeclared every interval execution. But the question is: why not only receive events in .on method? You probable don't need to wrap it in a interval, and then, the events will be handled in the exact time you expect to. If you want a delay, maybe you can set a timeout inside the .on callback.

Comment: My example was more simple just to ilustrate the idea, so my assumption is true that the data will wait until the setInterval call the function?

Comment: You may need to test it in real case, but I think you are correct in this assumption.